# There are 2 square brackets around 2 notes in this trombone part. What does it mean?

Tags: notation

[image]

In this trombone part there is square brackets and slide numbers on these notes. What does this indicate?

Comment: The meaning of brackets is typically context dependent. If possible, please add the title, composer, and a picture that includes a measure or two on either side of the bracketed part.

Comment: Is this a treble clef or bass clef part?

Comment: Given how it lines up perfectly with what we know about trombone and E and F, almost certainly it's bass clef.  But a clef would still be nice:)

Comment: The only certain answer, from the limited context provided, is that we don't know what the brackets mean. We can probably assume the numbers are slide positions (for bass clef notes) but, again, lack enough context to say why the previous F, presumably in 1st, should be followed by an E in 7th!

Brackets sometimes indicate 'omit this'. But why would meticulous instructions be given for something that wasn't to be played? I've never known them mean 'nota bene'.

Answer (score 1):

A trombonist would normally play the E in 2nd position and the F in 1st.  Alternatively, the notes can be played in 7th ad 6th positions, one partial higher.  Without seeing the larger context of the piece I don't know why they are to be played so far out, but one might guess that nearby notes of low B and C (which can only be played out there)* might make the passage easier.

I've not seen the brackets before, I can only guess they are there to call attention to the alternate positions.

The * above is to say that a trombone equipped with an F attachment can play the low B and C in 2nd and first position with the trigger.

Comment: Couldn't the brackets simply mean that those those notes could be omitted?